# Unable to connect server for database access from my local system

Tags: php, linux

```
if (!($connection = ssh2_connect("serveraddress", port)))
 {

       echo "[FAILED]\n";
}
else

    echo "Connect";
```

this not connecting to server.

Comment: I'd like to say that this question.. is actually the best example that i've seen on how not to post a question on SO, please check the FAQ, or even read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: will you suggest me the connection for accessing database from linux server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't connect to a database through ssh protocol.

why not using PDO ? http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php